# "tools.jar unexpected" error occurred when running the run.bat in jboss

Tags: java, jboss

I'm installing JBoss 4.0.0 to my machine. 
But it gives me an error saying tools.jar unexpected  when running the run.bat in jboss. What did I missed here? Any idea?

Java Home : C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.6.0

JRE Home : C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre1.6.0

Answer (score 1):

The error is because of the **space** in

> C:\Program Files (x86)

Move(Cut + Paste) the JDK folder into a path that doesn't have space

Example:

> C:\Java

Now, the JDK Path will be

> C:\Java\jdk1.6.0

Now set `JAVA_HOME` to the above folder.